# Consuming Restful web service using jQuery client

Tags: java, jquery, rest

I am trying to learn the restful web service Post logic.
In order to test the Post logic i am using jQuery to invoke the restful API.

The code i used for testing mentioned below.
Restful API code.

```
package com.crunchify.tutorials;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

    @Path("/")
    public class CrunchifyRESTService {


    @POST
    @Path("/verify")

    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public RestBean MsgRsc(RestBean message) {

        System.out.println(message.id1);

        return message;

    }

RestBean class.

    package com.crunchify.tutorials;

    import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

    public class RestBean {
    @JsonProperty("param1")
    int id1;
    @JsonProperty("param2")
    int id2;
    }
```

Jquery client.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jsonview.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.jsonview.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          function testWebservice(){
            var url = "http://localhost:8081/TestPost/verify";
            var params = {param1:1,param2:2};
            var jsonParam = JSON.stringify( params );

            $.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#responseContent").JSONView(response);
                    console.log("Success");
                },
                error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                  console.log("Failed");
                }
        } );
          }      
    </script>

    </head>
    <div style="margin:20px 0 0 20px;">
    <input type="button" value="Test" id="a2" onclick="testWebservice()"/>
    </div>
    <div id="responseContent" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;height:  500px;overflow: scroll;width: 500px; margin: 20px 0 0 20px;">
</div>
</html>
```

When i test using the jQuery client, i am receiving below error.Not sure how to resolve it.

```
 Apr 27, 2017 11:58:01 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2766)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1519)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There is no `data` object in `POST` call. So, looks like you are not passing any payload at all?

Comment: Add the following property 'data: jsonParam' to your ajax call

Comment: You are not posting any data. Also you'll have to set an Accept header.

Comment: Thanks Kishan. After adding data: jsonParam to the jQuery call, its working fine.